# Fake image crop and displaying it using coordinates

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

We have square portraits that are displayed via background-size: cover, most of the images looks bad now. The obvious choice is to add cropping option via cropper.js or whatever and create new image. But is it possible to create fake cropping interface, save coordinates and display original image in a way user *cropped* it? This is abstract question since i'm not a coder, but I need to present this idea with *abstract* solutions, so coders could implement it. Is it possible to solve this problem without creating new image?

[image]

Comment: do you want an example of cropping image  using reactjs ? is it okey to use an external package ?

Comment: can be done just fine with CSS (`clip-path`). What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @monim the cropping itself is not a problem, we can implement that, I'm asking if it's possible to achieve this without creating new cropped image ie via coordinates.

Comment: @tacoshy We haven't, i'm doing _presentation_ and I need to know if there any solution to do this, if it is what _hack_ we could use. I will look into clip-path, thanks!

Comment: You can use `object-position` or `background-position` to center your image after cropping. And you can also store this value in url params. https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-panka-vdu1uu?file=/src/App.js